# Vertical tabs with flex box

Tags: css, flexbox

I would like to accomplish a vertical tabs layout, so on the left would be the tabs and on the right the tab contents. The challenge is that I have to adhere to a specific markup which makes things complicated.

Below is my last attempt, I cant make the tabs fill in the space left by the content:

```css
ul{
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.tabs-container{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-width: 400px;
}

.tab{
 width: 100px;
 background-color: gray;
}

.tab-content{
  display: none;
}
.tab-content.active{
  display: block;
  height: 100px;
  order: -1;
  align-self: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<ul class='tabs-container'>
  <li class='tab'>tab one</li>
  <li class='tab-content active'>contents tab one</li>
  <li class='tab'>tab two</li>
  <li class='tab-content '>contents tab two</li>
  <li class='tab'>tab three</li>
  <li class='tab-content'>contents tab three</li>
</ul>
```

Is there a solution for this problem using css flex box?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="obj"><div class="tab">Tab1</div><div class="tab-c">TabContent1</div></div>
    <div class="obj"><div class="tab">Tab2</div><div class="tab-c">TabContent2</div></div>
</div>
<style>
    .container {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        background-color: tomato;
    }
    .obj {
        display: flex;
        /*no need of specify the flex direction here it's row by default*/
        background-color: orange;
        margin: 10px;
    }
    .tab {
        width: 50px;
        background-color: yellow;
    }
    .tab-c {
        width: 150px;
        background-color: white;
    }
</style>
```

This is probably not the most elegant way to do it but it's work for my needs